# Muting SpeechRecognizer's beep sound

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using SpeechRecognizer API for my app, and everytime it starts, it plays "beep" sound.

I'd like to know how to mute it, So I could implement one of my own.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get any further with this?

Comment: @Georg No, Do you have an answer?

Comment: nope... :( but i'd be interested in one!

Comment: I've got to do what I put on the following link:
[Muting the Google voice recognition beep sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734868/muting-the-google-voice-recognition-beep-sound/37809750#37809750)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a button to activate and deactivate the recognizer you can mute sound onclick.
This doesnt work fantastically if you have it listening constantly, however for button clicks it should be fine :)

```
private AudioManager manager;
manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (isChecked)
    {
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

    }
    else
    {
        manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        speech.stopListening();
        speech.cancel();
    }
```

Hope this helps (sorry if this is abit of a necrothread)