# How to change Speech To Text Starting Tone in Google Voice

Tags: android, speech-to-text, google-voice

I am developing  android app using Google Voice.It's working fine for me.I need to change the Speech To Text Start tone (Indication).I have searched in speech.java ,but i could not any method to change the tone.I want to replace some other mp3 (beep sound).
Please help me to do this.

Comment: Maybe this question will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734868/muting-the-google-voice-recognition-beep-sound

Comment: where can i able to change the mp3 file.